# OWIN MVC - Multiple LoginProviders, Current LoginProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

I have multiple login providers available. I can login with external account or using forms auth. Everything works fine. 
I'am redirecting user to HomePage, and now i would like to know which login provider was used.

Is there is a possibility to find out in controller, which loginprovider was used?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you want to know the login provider?

Comment: I have exception log in which i want to include information about which login provider was used during login. Also like to show coresponding icon near current logged user

Answer (score 0):

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
string provider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider; // Facebook, Google, Twitter, Microsoft...
```

Comment: This will work only on ExternalLoginCallback request. In other requests externallogininfo is null, so i cannot use it in any controller action.

Comment: @PiotrDory if you capture the login info in ExternalLoginCallback and can store it in Session, you could access it later. I haven't tried this, but it sounds plausible.

Comment: That is not enough :/ It is possible to start new session with already logged user

Answer (score 0):

I got this working although it's not something that would work in all cases.

Here's the code I used in a HomeController function:

```
// get the provider name
var authCtx = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
var usrMgr = authCtx.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = usrMgr.FindByName(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
var extLoginInfo = usrMgr.GetLogins(user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
var loginProvider = extLoginInfo.LoginProvider.ToLower();
```

The main issue here is that I'm not getting the actual login provider that the user is currently logged-in with. I'm just getting the first login provider associated with this user (which in my case happens to be the same, so it works).

Would be great to find a way to get the actual provider that the user is currently logged-in with.